# How Do I Nest Spacebars Tags?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I have a problem. I have a collection of documents in my database, and I would like to display each document depending on whether a session variable corresponding to that document is set.

To illustrate my problem, let me give a simplified example.

```
Meteor.myTemplate.helpers({
  stuff: [
    {name: 'item1'},
    {name: 'item2'}
    {name, 'item3'},
    {name: 'item4'},
    {name: 'item5'}
  ],
  isActive: function (itemName) {
    return Session.get(itemName + 'IsActive');
  }
});
```

Now, what I would like to do is this:

```
{{#each stuff}}
    {{#if isActive {{name}} }}
      {{> someTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

But since nested tags like this are not supported, I can't do this. I am looking for a way to achieve this without having to write:

```
{{if isActive 'item1'}}{{> someTemplate}}{{/if}}
{{if isActive 'item2'}}{{> someTemplate}}{{/if}}
{{if isActive 'item3'}}{{> someTemplate}}{{/if}}
{{if isActive 'item4'}}{{> someTemplate}}{{/if}}
{{if isActive 'item5'}}{{> someTemplate}}{{/if}}
```

Which is possible if the data is static like in the above example (instead of coming from a database cursor), but it is not really practical in any case, especially with a lot of items. Furthermore, this style probably makes every programmer cringe.

Comment: Can be tricky if you use Session to keep track of active vs not. Are you able to store isActive as a property to the document? That way you can do something like `return Items.find({isActive: true})` and `each` will only return documents that are marked isActive.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have a multi-select dropdown, and depending on which options people have selected, other options should appear in another multi-select dropdown. To make your suggestion work I could use a slightly more convoluted approach were I use the `transform` option with `find` to filter out results. This trick is useful when the helper does not have access to the appropiate context!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the context of isActive is a `stuff`, then `this.name` should be available to the helper:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  isActive: function(itemName) {
    return Session.get(this.name + 'IsActive');
  }
});
```

Your template would look like:

```
{{#each stuff}}
  {{#if isActive}}
    {{> someTemplate}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```